# How to map values from one json schema to another json schema in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a json schema with the below schema:

```
   Country:{
          city:{
             value1:0,
             value2:1,
             value3:2,
             value4:3,
             value5:4,
             value6:5
             }
           }
```

i need to map the above values to another json schema  as below:
how to build the below schema based on extracting the information from the above schema?

```
        Country:{
            city:{
                value_1:0,
                value_2:1,
                suburb1:{
                    value_3:2,
                    value_4:3
                    },
                suburb2:{
                    value_4:4
                    value_5:5
                    }
                },
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve it as the follows:

```
import json

country_json = '''Country:{
          city:{
             value1:0,
             value2:1,
             value3:2,
             value4:3,
             value5:4,
             value6:5
             }
           }'''

country_json = country_json.replace(" ", "").replace('\n', '')
country_json = country_json.replace(':', '":').replace(':{', ':{"').replace(',', ',"')
country_json = '{"' + country_json + '}'

country = json.loads(country_json)

print(country)

city = country['Country']['city']

suburb1 = {}
suburb2 = {}

for k, v in city.items():
    if k in ["value3", "value4"]:
        suburb1.update({k: v})

    if k in ["value4", "value5"]:
        suburb2.update({k: v})

city.update({
    'suburb1': suburb1,
    'suburb2': suburb2,
})

for k in ["value3", "value4", "value5", "value6"]:
    city.pop(k)

print(json.dumps(country, indent=4))

country = json.dumps(country, indent=4).replace('"', '')
print(country)
```

Comment: yup. worked... thanks. i would be interested to know if some value is missing in the input file... for example value2 is missing, how do we make a generic script to check for the available keys and map them accordingly to the new json format

Comment: use `get(k, default_avlue)` other than `[k]`